# Why are uploaded images via Django admin not showing up in the production server?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have the following model field

```
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=municipality_logo_file_name)
```

and function that uploads the image to the desired location.

```
def municipality_logo_file_name(instance, filename):
    name, extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return os.path.join('municipality', 'logo', str(uuid.uuid4()) + extension.lower())
```

In the development mode, a file uploads correctly to for example /media/municipality/logo/1e3cc24a-841b-4577-aa59-b53e5b10420b.png and then displays correctly in the template using

```
<img src="{{ municipality.logo.url }}" alt="Logo obce" style="max-height: 8rem; width: auto">
```

In the production, file uploads well, but does not display in the template and the url cannot be followed to display image, the response is

```
Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

Using IIS and wfastcgi.py.

Any hint as to why this might be happening would be much appreciated.

Comment: What server are you using? You have to configure the server to serve the media files, as it's not done by django in development.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model)
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to='video-image/')

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        return '%s%s' % (settings.HOST, self.image.url) if self.image else ''
```

Comment: <img src="{{ image.logo_url }}" alt="Logo obce" style="max-height: 8rem; width: auto">

Comment: Please add more details to your code and the comment code should be in answer please do that too.

Comment: Hi, in the models I am creating image url and saving it with image if {{image.url}}  method does not work, you can use this method. This method request for image url and base respose with url. On {{image.url}} method you request for image and base send you image and .url try to take image's url its not true way you can use method i wrote on top and you will sense its usefull